# Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor not monitoring Intent.ACTION_CALL

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I have a simple test case for testing whether an outgoing call is initiated on a button click or not.

```
public void testCalling(){
    IntentFilter callFilter = new IntentFilter();
    callFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    callFilter.addDataScheme("tel:");
    ActivityMonitor mMonitor = new ActivityMonitor(callFilter, null, false);
    getInstrumentation().addMonitor(mMonitor);

    mSolo.clickOnText("CALL");

    assertTrue(0 < mMonitor.getHits());
    sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL); 
}
```

Although the Intent is called(the outgoing call is made), my ActivityMonitor fails to register it.
The Stack trace is

```
05-28 17:11:09.183: I/ActivityManager(71): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:+xxxxxxx cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster }
```

Please help

The only other resource that i could find was [this discussion which ended without any solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/5OLGwZRn3zk) on android developers group

Answer (score 3):

I thought to have the same problem. Later I found out that my activity monitor didn't work because robotium registers it's own monitor that always hits, blocking any other monitors including mine.

Answer (score 1):

After having the same issue and playing around a bit, I got it to work.

Take the colon off "tel". Then you should have a hit on your monitor.

```
    public void testMakeCall(){
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        filter.addDataScheme("tel");

        ActivityMonitor activityMonitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(filter, null, false);

        makeCall();

        assertTrue(activityMonitor.getHits() == 1);
    }
```